# Dual of concave function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

If $U(x)$ is strictly increasing and strictly concave and $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ U'(x) = 0, prove that its dual: $$U^{*}(y) = max_x \{U(x) - xy\}$$ is convex.

Does anyone know how to prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you meant $\max_{x} \{ U(x) - xy \}$?

Comment: I think the definition is not right.

Comment: @littleO, I think it has to do with that fact that $U$ is smooth

Comment: Yes, sorry the max is meant to be for the two terms. I have changed it.

Comment: The title says the dual is convex, but the question says it should be concave.  Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: Yes. Show the dual is convex. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

In convex analysis, the convex conjugate of a function $f$ is usually defined to be 
\begin{equation*}
f^*(y) = \sup_x \, \langle y, x \rangle - f(x).
\end{equation*}
With this definition, $f^*$ is *convex* because a supremeum of convex functions is convex.
(And for each $x$, the function $y \mapsto \langle y, x \rangle - f(x)$ is convex.)

The function $U^*$ as you have defined it is convex by a similar argument.  We don't need any assumptions on $U$ beyond $U:\mathbb R^n \to [-\infty,\infty]$ to reach this conclusion.